# iOS import files into my application

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions, ios-sharesheet

I am creating an iOS application through which users can print the files on their device. From my application, I can access the files on the device though the `DocumentPicker` provided by other apps such as iCloud Drive, Dropbox, etc.

Now, I want to add a functionality where user can share the file with my application through an other application. I created an `Action Extension` for that.
For example, if I select an Image in the Photos application and select `Share` I get my extension in the Share sheet and when I select it, I also get the URL of the file. Next, I am creating a zip file of this file to send it to my server. But the issue is, the zip file is always empty. The code I am using is as below:

**In Action Extension's viewDidLoad()**

```
if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String) {
    itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String, options: nil, 
        completionHandler: { (image, error) in
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                print("Image: \(image.debugDescription)")
                //Image: Optional(file:///Users/guestUser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/00B81632-041E-47B1-BACD-2F15F114AA2D/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0004.JPG)
                print("Image class: \(image.dynamicType)")
                //Image class: Optional<NSSecureCoding>
                self.filePaths.append(image.debugDescription)
                let zipPath = self.createZip(filePaths)
                print("Zip: \(zipPath)")
            }
         })
}
```

And my `createZip` function is as follows:

```
func createZipWithFiles(filePaths: [AnyObject]) -> String {
    let zipPath = createZipPath()  //Creates an unique zip file name

    let success = SSZipArchive.createZipFileAtPath(zipPath, withFilesAtPaths: filePaths)

    if success {
        return zipPath
    }
    else {
        return "zip prepation failed"
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can create a zip of the shared files?

Comment: Is `SSZipArchive` returning an error?  Are you sure you have write access to the `zipPath` and read access to all of the paths in `filePaths`?

Comment: No it does not give any error. It creates a zip file at `zipPath`, hence I have write access at `zipPath`. And, the files in `filePaths` are image files coming from the default Photos application. In the logs it says that the file does not exist at the mentioned position but I can see the file if I navigate through the terminal (for simulator).

Comment: Using `image.debugDescription` is not the way to get a file path to the image. First, what is the actual type of `image` in the completion handler? What is the output of `image.debugDescription`?

Comment: @rmaddy: image is of type `NSSecureCoding` and the output of `image.debugDescription` is somethings like`fie:///Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/---xx-xx-xx/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0004.jpg`

Comment: You have post 2 func. In the first you use self.createZip(filePaths), and in the second you post func createZipWithFiles, but i dont see any createZip method..

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano: As I have mentioned in the comments, `createZip()` function just creates a unique file name. So it returns a string like `xxx-yy-zzz.zip`.

Comment: @PrerakSola Update your question with the actual and complete output of the line `print("Image: \(image.debugDescription)")`.

Comment: @rmaddy: Added the complete output in the comment below the print statement.

Comment: OK, now add the output of `print("Image class: \(image.dynamicType)")`.

Comment: @rmaddy added that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary issue is that you are blindly adding `image.debugDescription` to an array that is expecting a file path. The output of `image.debugDescription` isn't at all a valid file path. You need to use a proper function on the `image` to obtain the actual file path.

But `image` is declared to have a type of `NSSecureCoding`. Based on the output of `image.debugDescription`, it seems that `image` is really of type `NSURL`. So you need to convert `image` to an `NSURL` using a line like:

```
if let photoURL = image as? NSURL {
}
```

Once you have the `NSURL`, you can use the `path` property to get the actual needed path.

So your code becomes:

```
if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String) {
    itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String, options: nil, 
        completionHandler: { (image, error) in
            if let photoURL = image as? NSURL {
                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                    let photoPath = photoURL.path
                    print("photoPath: \(photoPath)")
                    self.filePaths.append(photoPath)
                    let zipPath = self.createZip(filePaths)
                    print("Zip: \(zipPath)")
                }
            }
    })
}
```

**Hint**: Never use `debugDescription` for anything other than a `print` statement. Its output is just some string that could contain just about any information and that output can change from one iOS version to the next.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Before this, as a workaround, I was creating a temporary image using `NSData` in my app's sandbox and than copying that image to the zip file to upload to the server. But your way saves the processing and memory overhead of creating an extra image.

Comment: @rmaddy, I implemented shared extension in my app, In iOS 13, my share extension app can not open main app to receive shared file/image because UIApplication.shared is unavailable now. Previous all version works fine. So, how could developer receive/import data from different sources ? Suppose i want to open a file to my app from gmail or drive,  any workaround ?